# Oracle SQL: Selecting a single row with the latest date between multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

My base table structure looks like this:

> CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE_TABLE
> {
>    ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
>    -- Other columns here,
>    CREATE_USER VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL,
>    CREATE_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
>    UPDATE_USER VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
>    UPDATE_DATE DATE
> }

What I want to do is select the id of the row with the highest update_date or create_date.  So something like this (although this doesn't work - pID is defined as an out variable in a stored procedure):

> SELECT ID, MAX(GREATEST(CREATE_DATE, UPDATE_DATE) as LAST_MODIFIED
> FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
> RETURNING ID INTO pID;

This would return a single id of essentially the last row that was modified in the table.  Little help?

P.S.  This is in Oracle11g.  I'm currently using MERGE to upsert rows into tables, and using this method to get the id of the last upserted row.  If you have any constructive criticism of this (potentially with an alternative solution), I'm all ears.  I've read plenty of arguments going both ways as to why this is good / bad.  I'm going to call this procedure in c#, so any other tips there is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the structure you want is this:

```
select id
from (SELECT ID
      FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
      order by GREATEST(CREATE_DATE, UPDATE_DATE) desc
     )
where rownum = 1
```

However, I suppose it is possible for one of the dates to be NULL.  If so:

```
select id
from (SELECT ID
      FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
      order by coalesce(GREATEST(CREATE_DATE, UPDATE_DATE), CREATE_DATE) desc
     )
where rownum = 1
```

These queries are ordering by the larger of the two values on each row, and then selecting the maximum value.

Comment: Yep, this is what I was looking for.  Was wondering if Oracle had a faster way to do it than selecting the first row of an ordered list.  This will work though :)

Comment: @craignewkirk . . . If performance is an issue, ask another question.  Reference this one and provide more information on the size of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Create a composite of all the ID's with all the date fields and then Max them with a rownum restirction to only get the first one.

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT ID, Max(FirstDateField) AS value
    FROM TableName
                WHERE ROWNUM=1
                GROUP BY ID
                ORDER BY Max(FirstDateField) DESC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Max(SecondDateField) AS value
    FROM TableName
                WHERE ROWNUM=1
                GROUP BY ID
                ORDER BY Max(SecondDateField) DESC
)
SELECT ID 
FROM A
WHERE ROWNUM=1
ORDER BY Value DESC
```

Comment: Hi Darren,

Appreciate the answer.  Do you know which is faster on a large dataset : yours or Gordon's?

Comment: I primarily work with SQL Server but if it does react in a similar way the modification I just made SHOULD make it a faster execution (adding the WHERE ROWNUM=1 to each of the grouped top queries). Indexing the Date fields is essential to make this query instance regardless of the size now.

Comment: Gotcha - appreciate the update.  I don't have enough reputation to vote up yet, but once I do I'll vote this up for the feedback.