# Oracle: Fastest way to UPSERT and return the last affected Row ID in oracle for large data sets

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, merge, upsert

This table schema in question is here:  [Oracle SQL: Selecting a single row with the latest date between multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951312/oracle-sql-selecting-a-single-row-with-the-latest-date-between-multiple-columns)

I'm working with a table that has over 5 million entries.  What is the fastest and most accurate way to upsert to this table AND return the last upserted row id using a stored procedure?

Most of what I've read recommends using the merge statement for upserts.  However, merge doesn't support returning into.

In our table, we have the CREATE_DATE, CREATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE, and UPDATE_USER fields that are updated as expected.  My thought was to create a stored procedure that returned the id of the row that has the latest date between those two columns and where the respective user data was equal to the current user data.  This is what the people who answered the referring question helped me with (thanks!).

However, I'm concerned about the combined execution time vs other methods, as well as the huge gaps created in sequences due to merging.  Calling a separate statement simply to get the id also seems a bit inefficient.  However, almost everything I've read says that merge is much faster than the pre-merge upsert statements.

Note that these are being called through a c#/asp web application.  Any help is appreciated :)

*edit*

Below is an example of the stored procedure I'm using for the Upsert.  Note that the CREATE_DATE and UPDATE_DATE columns are updated with triggers.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE     P_SAVE_EXAMPLE_TABLE_ROW
(
    pID IN OUT EXAMPLE_TABLE.ID%type,
    --Other row params here
    pUSER IN EXAMPLE_TABLE.CREATE_USER%type,

    pPLSQLErrorNumber OUT NUMBER, 
    pPLSQLErrorMessage OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
MERGE INTO USERS_WORKGROUPS_XREF USING dual ON (ID=pID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (--OTHER COLS--, CREATE_USER) VALUES (--OTHER COLS--, pUSER)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
            --OTHER COLS--
            UPDATE_USER=pUSER
        WHERE ID=pID;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        pID := 0;
        pPLSQLErrorNumber := SQLCODE;
        pPLSQLErrorMessage := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 256);
        RETURN;

    -- STATEMENT TO RETURN LAST AFFECTED ID INTO pID GOES HERE
END;
```

Comment: Also, I don't want to add more columns to this table just to keep track of the upsert statement.  This was recommended elsewhere for someone using merge.

Comment: Also something to consider: how to handle exceptions if the merge succeeds but the request to get the last row id fails?

Comment: how many rows are typically inserted or updated?  1, 100, 1000000?

Comment: Sure, I'll add more info on the merge statement above.  In this case it's typically 1 row per execution.

Comment: @jonearles - yeah, that's what I was trying to figure out.  Is MERGE fast enough to mitigate having to call two queries?  Also, what happens if the merge succeeds but the row to get the latest id bombs out?  As far as speed goes, I could add indexes to the date columns used to retrieve the last used id, but from what I understand those would slow down inserts (although not sure by how much).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to return the maximum value of a sequence-generated PK on the table then I'd just run a "Select max(id) .." directly afterwards. If other sessions are also modifying the table then maybe reading the currval of the sequence would be better.

Comment: Hi David - Appreciate the answer.

Unfortunately this won't work (at least how I envision it).  Multiple sessions are modifying the table and merge increments the sequence value whether a row is inserted or updated.  If I get the curval of the sequence on an update, the id of the row updated will be different than the curval.  

Also,from what I understand, there's no way for me to distinguish if a row was inserted or updated during a merge without adding columns to the table to track this.

Comment: Is your sequence generation part of the merge statement? could it be pushed into a trigger to fire only on insert?

Comment: Nope, it's only called on a trigger when inserting a row.  Part of the way MERGE is built is that it automatically increments any sequences on the table whether regardless of whether you're inserting or updating.  This is what causes the sequence gaps mentioned above.  When you update a row, the sequence increments anyway.

Comment: Hmmm I understood that only occurs when the sequence is referenced as part of the query itself. As far as triggers are concerned, statement level triggers certainly fire but I believe that row level insert and update triggers behave correctly on merge. There's a demo here that also suggests that. http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:25733900083512 So you might like to verify. I'd do it myself but I'm at a conference.

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate the link.  That thread confirms my suspicions.  I thought that merge might be tripping both insert and update triggers, but didn't have any evidence.  I have the sequence incrementing in the before insert row trigger, which gets hit by merge.

Comment: That should just be for actual inserts though, is that right? An update-through-merge shouldn't execute a row-level insert trigger.

Comment: Nope, the MERGE hits the sequence no matter what.  According to the link you posted, it looks like the only triggers that are exclusive to insert or update during a merge are the After Update Row and After Insert Row triggers.  All before inserts are triggered every time.

Comment: My read of it is that a merge that performs an update executes all the statement triggers (BIS, BUS, AUS and AIS), but only the row triggers BUR and AUR -- B*I*R and B*I*S are not executed. Similarly, a merge that performs only an insert executes BIS, BUS, AUS, AIS, BIR and AIR, but not BUR and AUR. SQLFiddle confirms that in 11.2 the row level treatment is correct. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82e6e/6 Also, if BIR executed on update and set the PK from the sequence then it would have changed the PK value as part of the update -- that would be a fatal problem for merges.

Comment: Hmm, the example on sqlfiddle works for me, and I'm pretty sure we're using 11.2.  I converted the project I'm working on to just use separte updates and inserts for now (deadlines), but when I have some time I'm going to compare the two to figure out why my sequence keeps getting hit.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the best answer since I haven't tested this yet.  Thanks for helping me out!